# Bind book from scanned PDF

Tags: book-design

I would like to produce a bound copy of [this book](http://www.kalemguzeli.net/kitaplik) provided as a scanned PDF. The pages should be printed centered on larger sheets with crop marks in the correct order for book printing.
For this I used the `geometry`, `pdfpages` and `crop` packages and wrote this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=193mm,paperheight=266mm]{geometry}

%\usepackage[cam,pdflatex,width=19.3cm,height=26.6cm]{crop}
\usepackage[cam,frame,a3,center,color=red]{crop}

%\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\crop[cross,frame]
%%\includepdf[pages={1,{}, 2-126}, signature=8, landscape]{kalemguzeli3_1.pdf}
\includepdf[pages={2-126}, signature=4, landscape]{kalemguzeli3_1.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately the pages do not really fit properly into the selected A3 paper size and do not have the physical page size of 193mm x 266mm.

How would I have to do this in order to have a PDF which I could use to print and make a proper book out of it again?

Comment: You want to take the text from a scanned PDF and retypeset it?  That's not possible with LaTeX.  You could OCR it into a text file, then munge it into a (La)TeX file, but LaTeX cannot do the OCR for you.

Comment: So you want to place the existing scanned PDF centered on larger pieces of paper with professional cropping margins in book-order so you can bind it to a book, don't you? You shouldn't use the term 'retypesetting' for this.

Comment: @martin Yes thats what I want. Unfortunately I did not find any other word. Which word does describe my problem?

Comment: @matthew No I do not want character recognization.

Comment: @adnc: I rephrased your post accordantly. Please correct it if I got it wrong.

Comment: @adnc: The original book size is 193 x 266mm, and you want to print it centered on A3 (which has 420 x 297 mm), correct? What size is the scanned PDF? It might be different than the original book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your link lists three books which seems to be a series I-III.
The first PDF I get is called `Kalem_Gzeli_-_Cilt_1.pdf` and not `kalemguzeli3_1.pdf` as in your code. This files is in A4 with some extra margin and note in the footer. I could be that the book is originally 193x266mm in size but was scaled to A4 in the scanning process.

So you have to clip off the margin from the PDF pages first and scale the resulting pages to the correct size.
The clipping can be done using the `clip` and `trim` options of `\includepdf`. It uses `\includegraphics` from the `graphicx` package internally and support all of its options. If you select the official paper size to 193x266mm `pdfpages` will scale the clipped PDF pages automatically to this size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=193mm,paperheight=266mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[cam,frame,a3,center,color=red]{crop}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\crop[cross,frame]
\includepdf[pages={2-126}, signature=4, landscape, clip, trim=20 45 20 45]{kalemguzeli3_1.pdf}

\end{document}
```

The four values given for `trim` are the amounts which are removed from the left, bottom, right and top. The default unit is `bp` (big points) i.e. Postscript points (72bp = 1inch), which is also the unit used by PDFs. I get some decent results with the above settings. However not every scanned page is placed really centered and is sometimes slightly rotated. You might need to use different `trim` values for different pages and maybe even try `angle` to compensate the rotation, but I imagine that this will have quite an impact on the quality.

Comment: Indeed you are right. It is very difficult to buy these books. I have the first and second, but not the third. I used the third part and cropped the advertisement url and created a new pdf which I called kalemguzeli3_1.pdf. The problem with trimming is that I need to do this for every single page. Thank you very much.

Comment: @adnc: I thought so much about the file name. I saw that the books are out of print when I searched for their original size.

Comment: indeet the original size of the book is 193mm x 266mm